# Use user and pass based on banner in telnet class of ruby

Tags: ruby, cmd, automation, telnet

I want to write a script that does a login with username and password based on the output of the banner from a connection made by Net::Telnet in ruby:

code to login and execute a few commands (commands are in file "commands"):

```
USER = "myuser"
PASS = "mypass"
USER2 = "my2ndUser"
PASS2 = "my2ndPass"

ENABLEPASS = "myenablepass"
ENABLEPASS2 = "my2ndEnablePass"

tn = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => line,
"Timeout" => 10,
"Waittime" => 0.1,
"Prompt" => /[#>:]/n) { |resp| print "==> "+resp}

tn.cmd(USER) { |c| print c }
tn.cmd(PASS) { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("terminal length 0") { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("en") { |c| print c }
tn.cmd(ENABLEPASS) { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("\n")  { |c| print c }

File.open('commands').each do |l|
tn.cmd(l) { |c| print c }
end
tn.cmd("\n")  { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("\n")  { |c| print c }


tn.close
```

Desired: same script but uses the 2nd parameters when it says "my2ndrouter" in the banner/MOTD of the router that is outputted when a login attempt is done (just before you have to insert your user ans pass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the scenario right, you can use `waitfor` to syphon in the data until you get the prompt to receive the user name. Then process the data in waitfor block to detect which of the two sets of parameters to use.

```
routers = [
  { "user" => "myuser", "pass" => "mypass", "enablepass" => "myendablepass" },
  { "user" => "my2ndUser", "pass" => "my2ndPass", "enablepass" => "my2ndEndablePass" }
]

tn = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => line,
"Timeout" => 10,
"Waittime" => 0.1,
"Prompt" => /[#>:]/n) { |resp| print "==> "+resp}

my_router = routers[0]
# Replace /login:/ with whatever regexp that matches your login prompt, e.g. your catch-all /[#>:]/n
tn.waitfor(/login:/) { |banner| my_router = routers[1] if banner.match("my2ndrouter") }

tn.cmd(my_router['user']) { |c| print c }
tn.cmd(my_router['pass']) { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("terminal length 0") { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("en") { |c| print c }
tn.cmd(my_router['enablepass']) { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("\n")  { |c| print c }

File.open('commands').each do |l|
tn.cmd(l) { |c| print c }
end
tn.cmd("\n")  { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("\n")  { |c| print c }


tn.close
```

Comment: Ok this works when I adapt this solution in the collecion to "user" => "myuser" ... and so on. Now I see the login, the user is inserted but then it hangs. (this is another problem doh) :)